# Error inserting multiple rows using entity framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I'm getting this error trying to insert more than one row on this relation.

> Conflicting changes detected.
>
> This may happen when trying to insert multiple entities with the same key

This is the code:

```
foreach (var newValue in values) 
{
    Container.EnviromentValues.AddObject(new EnviromentValue() 
    { 
        key = newValue.Key,
        value = newValue.Value,
        env_id = some_int
    });
}

return Container.SaveChanges() > 0;
```

Comment: What's the primary key of `EnvironmentValues` table? Is it `env_id`?

Comment: the primary key is a column named "id" and it's identity too.